# Swift get file extension from web link

Tags: swift

I have web link, that is something like:

```
http://hr-platform.nv5.pw/image/comp_1/pdf-test.pdf
```

It may vary in text or extension. What i want is, get "pdf" string and woule be nice to have name of file, which is in that case - "pdf-test".

How to get those strings from web link? Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do it by using `NSString` with `pathExtension` for the file extension:

```
let url: NSString = "http://hr-platform.nv5.pw/image/comp_1/pdf-test.pdf" // http://hr-platform.nv5.pw/image/comp_1/pdf-test.pdf
let fileExtension = url.pathExtension // pdf
let urlWithoutExtension = url.deletingPathExtension // http://hr-platform.nv5.pw/image/comp_1/pdf-test
```

As @David Berry suggested use the `URL-class`:

```
let url = URL(string: "http://hr-platform.nv5.pw/image/comp_1/pdf-test.pdf")
let fileExtension = url?.pathExtension // pdf
let fileName = url?.lastPathComponent // pdf-test.pdf
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the URL class:

```
let url = URL(string: "http://hr-platform.nv5.pw/image/comp_1/pdf-test.pdf")
print(url?.pathExtension)
print(url?.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent)
```

Comment: Much cleaner solution, good answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
let urlStr = "http://hr-platform.nv5.pw/image/comp_1/pdf-test.pdf"

var  componentsArr = urlStr.components(separatedBy: "/")
if let fileName = componentsArr.last {
    print(fileName)
}
```